# Error on retrieving json data through django templates in javascript gives Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am rendering the json response data through apiview in django restframework, to html template list.html where i want to retrieve this data in a javascript code.
However everytime it gives "missing ) after argument list error" even though they are not actually present in the data received (as seen in inspect tools of chrome)

Getting the error on

```
var list =JSON.parse("{{data|safe}}")
```

[image]

The code apiview from views.py which is rendering the data is :

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def memeList(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        meme = Meme.objects.all().order_by('-meme_id')[:100]
        serializer = MemeSerializer(meme, many=True)
    elif request.method=='POST':
        serializer=MemeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

    serJS = JsonResponse(serializer.data,safe=False)
    return render(request,'list.html',{'data':serJS.content})
```

Any solution for this as i have tried all available solutions on the internet still the problem isn't resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the last line in the snippet from your views.py file:

```
return render(request, 'list.html', {'data': serJS.content})
```

Here, `serJS.content` returns a bytestring representing the content. To parse it as JSON, you need to convert it to string, render in the html body and then it will be parsed as JSON correctly. Use this instead:

```
return render(request, 'list.html', {'data': serJS.content.decode()})
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** do this:

```
var list = JSON.parse("{{data|safe}}")
```

`{{ data|safe }}` will render Python objects that cannot be (reliably) parsed as JSON.

What you likely want is to use the [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) template filter. Follow the steps in the docs to get your data as JSON in JavaScript.

Comment: It gives error of "unexpected token &" on not using safe filter. The problem was in the views where I was passing data I had to pass to decode function first as mentioned in accepted answer..

Comment: data was a `bytes` object, that can't be represented in JSON. You still should not use `JSON.parse("{{data|safe}}")`. It's a XSS vulnerability waiting to happen. Use `json_script`.